# Git repository on different OS's

Tags: github

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and originally was editing and pushing to Github via Windows through the Rails Terminal.

I’ve now switched to Fedora and am wondering what the correct method of cloning the original repository is? I’ve read [this](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository) article which discusses duplicating a repository from Github, but I’m curious if I should actually just create a branch from the original and then merge. I may switch back and forth between Windows and Fedora so which method would be best?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind a Distributed Version Control System (DVCS) like git is to allow check-in/checkout of code from a variety of places. This makes the decision on branching solely one of practicality and not on operating system or other architecture (unless of course your branches *are* for separate architectures or operating systems).

There are some best practices to follow with regards to branching. I highly recommend reading the answer at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices for an overview of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it matters which OS you're on. The commands are the same. You will do a `clone`, `push`, and `pull` (and whatever else) on both machines. Just make sure you push to the origin before you switch machines and do a pull from the origin after.

The difference might come if you prefer to use a desktop client GUI to interact with Git than the comand line.

Answer (score 0):

Git is Git. There is no difference command dependent OS.

Answer (score 0):

Although Git was initially developed for *nix platforms, it (now) works more or less seamlessly on Windows.

Some things do differ though and you should take them into account if you foresee to switch back and forth between *nix and Windows.

- Handling of symlinks works on *nix but is barely supported on Windows.
- Paths greater than 260 chars long are supported on *nix, not on Windows.
- Line endings. Regarding the files in the working directory, Windows prefers CRLF, *nix prefers LF. However, Git also prefers LF when it comes to storing files as blobs in its object database. The easiest way to work around this is to create a `.gitattributes` files in your repository. This will take care of converting the line endings on the fly for you, depending on the OS you're running Git against. More information about this **[in this GitHub help topic](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)**.

Beside these ones you shouldn't see any major difference from the git perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Git works fine on Windows and Linux, and you don't need separate branches for each. Simply run `git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` (replacing the text in caps) on Linux, then commit, push, and pull as usual.